# How do I keep rotated image inside lower boundary in dash?

Tags: html, css, plotly-dash

My dash body is:

```
body = html.Div([html.H1("My dashboard")
, dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(radio_buttons)
        , dbc.Col(html.Div(dbc.Alert("One of three columns", color="primary", id='output-image', 
                  className='bg-success', style={'height': '300px', 'width': '400px'})))
        , dbc.Col(html.Div(dbc.Alert("One of three columns", color="primary", id='output-address')))

        ],style={'height': '300px'})
, dbc.Row([dbc.Col(create_data_table(df))])
    ],
id="dash-container",)
```

and I have a function which returns a rotated image thus:

```
 return (html.Img(src='data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(encoded_image.decode('utf-8')), style={'max-height':'100%', 'max-width':'100%'}))
```

when rotation is 0 or 180 the image fits in its container:

[image]

but 90 or 270 it doesn't:
[image]

How can I keep the image in this box preserving its aspect ratio?

Comment: Do you want the rotated image to shrink to fit the box or to remain at its original size with the bits that are outside the box not visible?

Comment: Shrink to fit, please.

Comment: @AHaworth there is a bounty on this qn now.

Comment: is there a working demo?

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj sorry, no. It is a Google Appengine app and quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `style={'max-height':'100%', 'max-width':'100%'}` or change it to `style={}`  if you need an input to the function.

Comment: Thanks, but that makes the image flow out of the container in both directions.